# jQuery получение определеного значения

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть Таблица и в ней есть строки `<td>` Получаю их значение с помощью 
jQuery таким образом. Но он дает мне все значения `td`. Как я могу получить значение, которое я хочу, а не все

```
$('td').each(function(){
  console.log($(this).html());
  alert($(this).html());
});
```

Таблица:

```
<table id="myform:myTable">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th scope="col">ID</th>
         <th scope="col">Name</th>
         <th scope="col">Address</th>
         <th scope="col">Email</th>
         <th scope="col">Phone</th>
         <th scope="col">Actions</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>2</td>
         <td>elvir</td>
         <td>simqayit</td>
         <td>sama.ibrahimov@mail.ru</td>
         <td>33-55-444</td>
         <td><script type="text/javascript" src="/Lesson05/faces/javax.faces.resource/jsf.js?ln=javax.faces&amp;stage=Development"></script><a href="#" onclick="jsf.util.chain(this,event,'return confirm(\'Are you sure\')','mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById(\'myform\'),{\'myform:myTable:0:j_idt23\':\'myform:myTable:0:j_idt23\'},\'\')');return false">Remove</a><input type="submit" name="myform:myTable:0:j_idt24" value="Edit" /></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Хочу получить только этот   `sama.ibrahimov@mail.ru`  маил а не прохождить по вем через цикл

Comment: Т.е. содержимое с определённой ячейки нужно?

Comment: да именно а цикл по всем проходит

Comment: Вам нужно для начала определиться какую ячейку Вам нужно. Задаётся либо номером строки (i) и номером колонки (j), тогда нужгая ячейка что-то такое `table.rows[i].cells[j].innerHtml`. Либо для каждой ячейки задаётся свой класс, при этом тоже логично использовать номера строк и ячеек в названии класса.. Так что получится те же яйца, вид сбоку.

Comment: Ахадада )да Сергей  со скриптом проблем нет на js я это сделал хотел у его фрэйма jquery это сделать ,и мне помогли .но веже jquery намного быстрее получается чем js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Можно через `index` элемента (работает, если известно в какой ячейке `email`):

```js
$('td').eq(3).each(function(){
  console.log($(this).html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="myform:myTable">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th scope="col">ID</th>
         <th scope="col">Name</th>
         <th scope="col">Address</th>
         <th scope="col">Email</th>
         <th scope="col">Phone</th>
         <th scope="col">Actions</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>2</td>
         <td>elvir</td>
         <td>simqayit</td>
         <td>sama.ibrahimov@mail.ru</td>
         <td>33-55-444</td>
         <td><script type="text/javascript" src="/Lesson05/faces/javax.faces.resource/jsf.js?ln=javax.faces&amp;stage=Development"></script><a href="#" onclick="jsf.util.chain(this,event,'return confirm(\'Are you sure\')','mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById(\'myform\'),{\'myform:myTable:0:j_idt23\':\'myform:myTable:0:j_idt23\'},\'\')');return false">Remove</a><input type="submit" name="myform:myTable:0:j_idt24" value="Edit" /></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

2) Если не известно, в какой именно ячейке находится, то вот так:

```js
$('td').each(function(){
  if(/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.exec(this.innerHTML)){
    console.log($(this).html());
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="myform:myTable">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th scope="col">ID</th>
         <th scope="col">Name</th>
         <th scope="col">Address</th>
         <th scope="col">Email</th>
         <th scope="col">Phone</th>
         <th scope="col">Actions</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>2</td>
         <td>elvir</td>
         <td>simqayit</td>
         <td>sama.ibrahimov@mail.ru</td>
         <td>33-55-444</td>
         <td><script type="text/javascript" src="/Lesson05/faces/javax.faces.resource/jsf.js?ln=javax.faces&amp;stage=Development"></script><a href="#" onclick="jsf.util.chain(this,event,'return confirm(\'Are you sure\')','mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById(\'myform\'),{\'myform:myTable:0:j_idt23\':\'myform:myTable:0:j_idt23\'},\'\')');return false">Remove</a><input type="submit" name="myform:myTable:0:j_idt24" value="Edit" /></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: С первым примером все понятно !Спасибо))а в вром примере есть такая строка

Comment: if(/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.exec(this.innerHTML)){

Comment: что она значит и принцип её действия .Буду благодарен щас пройдет 3 минуты приму ваш ответ

Comment: @elik, это регулярное выражение http://javascript.ru/regexp . С помощью него я проверяю строку на валидность, т.е. проверяю, является ли строка email`ом

Comment: точно также можно проверить является ли строка символовбуквой или цифрой??

Comment: @elik, да. Буквы: `/^\w$/`. Цифры: `/^\d$/`

Comment: Сколькоже полезный функций у этого ява скрипта _